# how to add Circular shape to a DropdownButton in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to know how to customize DropdownButton by adding circular shape border like below in the picture .

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do that in a simple way. You have to edit the classes `_DropdownMenuPainter` and `_DropdownMenuState` from `dropdrown.dart`, which is part of the Flutter's material package.

In `_DropdownMenuPainter`, change the `BoxDecoration` radius set in constructor:

```dart
_DropdownMenuPainter({
    ...
    this.resize,
  }) : _painter = BoxDecoration(
    ...
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),  // Set the radius you want here
    boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[elevation],
  ).createBoxPainter(),
        super(repaint: resize);
```

In `_DropdownMenuState`, inside the method `build()`, wrap the `Material` widget with a `ClipRRect` and set its `borderRadius` the same as you set for `_DropdownMenuPainter`:

```dart
return FadeTransition(
  opacity: _fadeOpacity,
  child: CustomPaint(
    ...
    child: Semantics(
      ...
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),  // This must be identical to the one set before
        child: Material(
          ...
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Notice that you'll lose those changes when you update Flutter.

#### Update:

I was going to make a PR to Flutter, but spent 1 hour trying to run the tests and had no success, so I'm not going to waste my time on this. Instead, I made a gist, so you can copy the whole file with the changes I made to your local Flutter copy.

https://gist.github.com/hugocbpassos/2a63594a21d7f231e97dd7dc1f18ee68

To use it, just set the `radius` property:

```dart
DropdownButton(
  radius: 16,
  items: [
    ...
  ],
);
```

Comment: I just changed this :   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0), in BoxDecoration of _DropdownMenuPainter , and it worked fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: There's a reason why you must also create a `ClipRRect`. If you increase the radius (24, for example) and click the first or last menu item, you'll see that the ripple will draw outside the dropdown menu. Using `ClipRRect` prevents that, so I really recommend you to use it, since this incorrect behaviour can happen even with 16 radius in some different screen sizes.

Comment: @HugoPassos Must say its an awesome implementation thanks.

Comment: The web page linked no longer exists :(